# MySqlCommand Returns Column Name, Not Value

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net

I have an issue where the following SQL command returns the column name, not the value in the column.

```
string sql = "SELECT @resource FROM db1.stuff WHERE (username = @userid)";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, command); //command was set earlier
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@resource", "cash");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", "testguy");

connection.Open();
var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

result returns "cash".

If I remove @resource and replace it with "cash", I get the desired value.

Am I doing something wrong? How do can I make this work with a Parameterized value?

Comment: You cannot use parameters as database object identifiers like column names.  (`select 'cash' from ...` returns `'cash'` n times) You are going to have to concatenate it yourself.

Comment: Parameters are used for *values*, not for *schema objects*.

Comment: Thank you .  I corrected the line like so:     string sql = String.Format("SELECT {0} FROM db1.stuff WHERE (username = @userid)", resource);  and it works as expected.

Comment: prolly a good idea to `SELECT \`{0}\` FROM db1.stuff`

Comment: What does '{0}' do differently than {0}?

Comment: If the column name in the variable had spaces or was reserved it must be wrapped in `\`\``